# PHP Storm code help, file included from another but PHP Storm does not know about it

Tags: phpstorm

I have a project where there are three files:

Class Master.php
Class Child.php
File  config.php

Master.php includes first config.php and then Child.php through require_once.

In config.php I have a global $variable.
In Child.php I use that $variable but PHP Storm is not aware about it.

The code helper only works if I include the config.php file directly in child.php.

Question:
How can I tell PHPStorm that Child.php is called from Master.php, so all includes from Master also apply for Child ?

Comment: I know -- it's a bit unrelated ... but why do you use globals? 1) Can that variable be replaced by a constant? 2) Have you tried replacing globals by static class (where all variables are done as static fields) .. or instance of a class implementing Registry pattern?

Comment: In any case: 1) PhpStorm does not actually tracks includes/requires (hierarchy of which file is include in which). 2) Lots of inspection have additional options -- `Settings | Inspections | PHP` -- find yours there and see if you can alter its' behaviour so that it works not in this-file-only scope (AFAIK it should). 3) If nothing -- please provide some simple example (simplify your 3 files and share them somehow so they can be downloaded and tested locally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments :

PhpStorm does not track variables in over different required files, but you can always use PHPdoc to make PhpStorm aware of it :

```
/** @include config.php */
```

or

```
/** @var $variable */
```